# An alternative to Powerpoint 2007 viewer than MS powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

The Powerpoint 2007 viewer, for unknown reasons, doesn't work in my machine. I've installed the SP1 also, but it behaves the same (it does not open).

I've installed Open Office, but its text rendering when presenting is awful.

Do you know any other good alternative to view pptxs / ppts?

I already have the presentation done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer really is your best bet. You're better off asking/figuring out how to get it running.

**Edit:** Try getting it up and running in Google Docs.

Comment: I have less than an hour to the presentation. Since every setup I got is not working, neither the update, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, google docs doesn't render animations but its fine ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it works out for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When I have had these problems in the past, a cheesy workaround is to save it as or print it to a PDF and use the PDF as the 'viewer'.

Answer (score 0):

[Sliderocket](http://www.sliderocket.com) does quite a nice job importing Powerpoint presentations. If you're not familiar with it, it's an online alternative to Powerpoint so it'd be accessible from any computer.